# Combining points with win percentage to get an efficient rating

Tags: statistics

We have a FIFA league set up between a few friends of mine. It's a fun way to keep track of the scores and who is the best player, however we have a little problem with the rankings.

At the moment, it is done on points. However this is unfair as it means the more games you play, the better the chance you have of being top of the table, and doesn't necessarily relate to skill as we play matches in pairs or threes and so if you have a good person on your team, you have a better chance of winning.

We tried to therefore do it by win percentage, but again, this isn't fair as you only need to play once, win and therefore have 100% win percentage and be top of the table.

I am hoping for a way that combines the two to make the rankings a lot more fair. If I knew some way of doing this, then maybe I could try and write it up in Excel.

I did consider the Elo rankings but they rely on weighting each game and have the losing team lose points. Each game, in our one, has equal ranking and we don't want a player to lose and therefore lose points as it means they won't want to play as much.

Can you guys give me any ideas and help me to try and think of a way of doing this?

Comment: You could use $(w+1)/(m+2)$, where $m$ is the number of matches played and $w$ is the number of matches won. Meaning everybody starts with a score of $0.5$. Optimal scores tend to $1$, abysmal scores tend to $0$.